# Font 'Trebuchet MS' is not available to the JVM

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using ubuntu OS for ireport pdf generation.The exception is Trebuchet MS not found by jvm.I have not installed msfont package in ubuntu.when i added external font in (option->font) to ireport tool then it is compiling and generating pdf But when i am generating through java code it is throwing exception.I added the ttf font jar to class path but still the exception is coming.Is jvm depends on font pkg installed in OS as Trebuchet MS is windows font which is not installed in my OS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [Font Extensions](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/jaspersoft-v3-7-font-extensions/) to deal with fonts. Then you'll get beautiful PDFs (or at least PDFs with Trebuchet MS).

Comment: Thanks mdahlman for your reply..i use Font Extensions in jasper ireport tool where it is working fine but while i am generating pdf uisng jasper API with jrxml template in ubuntu OS it throwing the exception.I added ttf file to class path still exception is coming.i have not installed MS ttf in ubuntu.so is jvm depends on MS ttf in OS rather in classpath.

Comment: If you are adding the .ttf file to the classpath, then you are not using font extensions. You need to create the relevant .jar file. This goes in the classpath, and then you should be all set.

Comment: after i installed the ms fonts in Ubuntu the `exception font not available at JVM` not coming but The pdf font is not exact font of Trebuchet MS i added the .ttf jar in class path.So is there any setting required .The pdf fonts are not bold also.

Comment: i solved the ans just open the ireport goto tool->option->fonts then install new font with proper ttf file then export with extension .jar and add that jar in class path.

Comment: @Anil I have the same problem and I already generated a font extension and put it in the classpath of my web app, but it doesn't work on Linux. Just Windows and inside iReport.

Comment: @Gustavo Do you get any exception.What is the java version you are using.I hope you followed my previous comment how to generate jar & add to classpath.

Comment: @Anil The problem was the font extension jar exported by iReport 5.6. I tried this time with Jaspersoft Studio 6.2 and the jar is a bit different. This new version works on both Windows and Linux. The differences I noticed are: 1. each font family is in it's own folder 2. the values inside the tags don't use ![CDATA[]] anymore.