# PDFs look differnet when exported by Jasper Reports on Windows and on Linux (Debian)

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, pdf-generation, awt

When we're exporting PDFs in Windows they look ok, but when deployed to test server on Linux, they look different, i.e. basically the situation is the same as in http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/faq.html#FAQ25

So according to Jasper FAQ, I should use the same font for AWT and PDF. But I do not have control over how AWT maps logical fonts to physical fonts (I do it for PDF, I am embedding Arial.ttf in generated PDF).

Do you have any suggestions, what can I do to match fonts that are used by AWT to calculate the size of text and the fonts embedded in PDF?

I'm using Jasper Reports 3.5.3 and I am not allowed to switch to new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [font extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667845/font-trebuchet-ms-is-not-available-to-the-jvm). This allows you to, for example, specify that the report uses Arial and to provide Arial even if you don't have control over the JVM and in the fonts installed on the machine.

Comment: I believe that font extensions appeared after version 3.5.3, in my version I do not have SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory class.

Comment: Font Extensions were added in JR 3.1.3. See the sample reference docs: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions

Comment: The docs You mention are wrong! They are suggesting that I should configure extensions called SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory, but in fact this factory is not present in version 3.5.3. I had to configure JR using SpringExtensionsFactory: I've copy-pasted and then adapted the configuration from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%203.6.1/ jasper-fonts.jar. Whew, that was NOT straightforward.

Comment: To summarize: in 3.5.3 the iReport tool does not have a functionality of exporting font-extensions jars, while later versions of iReport have such functionality, but exported jars contain configuration for SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory whis is not present in 3.5.3. So if anybody wants to use fonts-extensions in 3.5.3, he have to download jasper-fonts.jar from jasperreports-fonts-3.6.1.jar - but remember to delete <property name="exportFonts"> from fonts.xml, as this property is not yet present in 3.5.3 (its added in 3.6.1).

Comment: Yikes. Thanks for posting the details. I knew that iReport didn't have the built-in exporting in the first release, but I didn't realize that Font Extensions had changed like that.

Comment: The double link tho "Use font extensions" > "You must use font extensions" > "Font extensions":D